# Keep NSButton highlighted

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, highlight, nsbutton

Quite simple question here. How can I keep a NSButton highlighted? It seems that whenever the user presses my highlighted button, the button becomes unhighlighted. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds (at best) somewhat confusing from a UI perspective. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
[[btnFilter1 cell] setHighlighted:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting it up in a XIB/NIB, you can set the type of the button to toggle/push on push off/etc.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing you want an almost one way toggle button? You could change the UIControlStateNormal to what the UIControlStateHighlighted.

```
-(void)buttonPressed
{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: This is not what I had in mind. Notice that I am interested in keeping a NSButton highlighted, not a UIButton. I am writing software for mac not iphone.